# absolute position a div on list items which are fluid in size

Tags: css

Hey guys i am trying to make an absolute positioned div like an overlay which expands to same width as the list item in a ul where the list item is fluid i mean in percentages.
i tried this but the white colored overlay div seems to pass the list item size and expand to whole browser.
can you please help
here is the fiddle
**http://jsfiddle.net/JVRnW/**

```
    .overlay
    {
        z-index: 3;


        position:absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width:100%;
        margin-top:0px;
        background-color: #fff;

    }
```

I want to get the overlay div same size as the LI block.
thanks.
please see my fiddle above . thanks.

Comment: just add a position relative to the ul li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make the `li` be the relative parent to position the `absolute` one:

```
ul li {
  position:relative;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/JVRnW/2/